# MapboxDirections don't move map

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

When MapboxDirections is showing the route from given origin and destination, it starts an animation and move the map to a place between points A(origin) and B(destination) (so the full route can be seen on screen).

What I want from the map is to don't move when it finds the route.

Can I achieve that? how?

Answer (score 1):

Add `flyTo: false`:

````js
var directions = new MapboxDirections({
  accessToken: 'YOUR-MAPBOX-ACCESS-TOKEN',
  unit: 'metric',
  profile: 'mapbox/cycling',
  flyTo: false
});
```js
````

Comment: I added ```flyTo: false``` but it does not work. It work on ```MapboxGeocoder``` for example, but not for ```MapboxDirections```, at least not work for me

Comment: Oh, my mistake.

Comment: Is there other way to stop map from moving?